# PHP - read and write data from csv file. Weird thing

Tags: php

So i made test code:

```
$fopen = fopen('./mydata.csv',"r");    
$data = fgetcsv($fopen, 1000, ",");
fclose($fopen);
$fp = fopen('mynewdata.csv','a');
fputcsv($fp,$data,',');
fclose($fp);
```

Content of mydata.csv file:

> string "some thing", sec string,next string

New content of mynewdata.csv file:

> "string ""some thing"""," sec string","next string"

My question is: Where this ' " ' comes from. What i do wrong that my output is different than input.

Few more obserwations:

When i do test like, with enclosure: '' -> empty string:

```
$data = fgetcsv($fopen, 1000,',','');
print_r($data);
```

It print's nothing insted of array with 2 rows, and that's the error i got from logs:
" FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  fgetcsv(): enclosure must be a **character**" So what would be the other option to give as the enclosure an empty string.

Comment: The output is actually correctly formatted (given the input), your original input wasn't

Comment: @MarkBaker Actually, the input was correctly formatted, too. Although `fputcsv` does that, it's not necessary to enclose fields that have spaces but don't have a field/row separator characters inside. AFAIR this is how Libre/OpenOffice saves CSVs by default and `fgetcsv` has no problem with parsing such input.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see by the [`fputcsv` documentation](https://www.php.net/fputcsv):

> int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = ',' [, string $enclosure = '"' ]] )

The last parameter is the enclosure. Since you haven't defined yours, it defaults to `"`, and then it has to escape your quote by placing a double quote.

To get rid of this, simply specify an empty string:

```
$fopen = fopen('./mydata.csv',"r");    
$data = fgetcsv($fopen, 1000, ",");
fclose($fopen);
$fp = fopen('mynewdata.csv','a');
fputcsv($fp,$data,',','');
//                    ^^
fclose($fp);
```

### But *why* does it do this by default?!

To avoid errors if you have commas in your strings. Imagine the following:

```
$data = array('my string', 'is a great string', 'and it is, very nice');
```

With an enclosure it would result in the following:

```
"my string","is a great string","and it is, very nice"
```

*Without* an enclosure, it would result in the following:

```
my string,is a great string,and it is, very nice
```

Which would be misinterpreted as 4 values instead of 3.

Comment: Yes, i've tried that before and the output was: "empty file".

Comment: The other weird thing according to what you sad and is in doc of that functions is that whan i add enclosure: 
$data = fgetcsv($fopen, 1000,',','');
print_r($data);
Suppose to print me array with 2 rows, but it print me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your replay. But the answer is different. I step on php bug:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51496

If some of you guy's out there know the solution, please write it. 
My php version 5.4.6.

Edit.

So to get rid of that problem insted of function fgetcsv and fputcsv i did way around:

```
$handle = fopen('./mydata.csv','r'); 
$data = fgets($handle);
$data = str_replace(', ','@!#$',$data);
$data = explode(',',$data);
$data = str_replace('@!#$',', ',$data);

$fp = fopen('mynewdata.csv','a');
$data = implode($data,',');
fwrite($fp, $data."\n");
fclose($fp);
fclose($handle);
```

The other solution. Insted of str_replace, explode, str_replace you can do:

```
$handle = fopen('./mydata.csv','r'); 
$data = fgets($handle);
$data = explode('","', preg_replace('/([^ ]),([^ ])/', '$1","$2', $data));
fclose($handle);
...
```